# Why is the name of my computer wrong in terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, laptop

I just transfered all of my files and settings over to a new laptop using Migration Assistant (on a mac). The name of my computer in terminal is wrong for some reason. It's unknown20c9d042dc93

The prompt looks like this

```
Last login: Thu Jul 19 19:46:15 on ttys001
unknown20c9d042dc93:~ Ryan$
```

How do I change the name to what it usually is, Ryan's Macbook?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Answer (score 3):

The value of the `$HOSTNAME` variable (which is actually what you're seeing there) is determined by a reverse DNS lookup of your IP address.

Which ever DNS server your Mac is configured to use has that in its database.

You can demonstrate this with the following command:

```
dig +short -x $(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

Use `en1` if you're on WiFi instead of wired.

Comment: That doesn't tell me how to fix it, I've tried restarting my router and my computer and that didn't fix anything

Comment: You need to edit the DNS zone and edit or remove that record.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: If it doesn't match what's in the **Sharing** preference pane and you don't know where to edit the zone file then you probably don't have access to do so. Try wandering around in your router config (if you have one, if not talk to your administrator).

Comment: This answer put me on a good path. I have a router from my cable company that apparently persists DNS names with little rhyme or reason. I worked around it by giving my machine a DHCP reservation to a previously unused IP. Prompt fixed. It also fixed the NETBIOS name (System Preferences > Network > Advanced > WINS) that previously matched the prompt.

I'll note that for me, on macOS 10.14, the value of $HOSTNAME was not the same as what was displaying at my prompt, and the specific dig command above didn't output anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

OS X gets a name from one of several places, depending on whether you're hooked up to a network and what you have and haven't configured.  One place you can set it is in the System Preferences under "Sharing" where it says "Computer name" on the top.  Also, under the "Network Settings", under "Advanced", look at the "WINS" tab where it shows the "NETBIOS Name".

Comment: I've checked in sharing and the advanced network settings and they're both correct but the name in terminal is still wrong