# Should I be concerned? My terminal says that someone's iPhone is connected to my Mac

Tags: mac, security, terminal, multiple-users

Recently I've been using a lot of public WiFi and fidgeting with my network settings to use network proxy tools like Burp.

Today I opened my terminal and saw this a foreign device as the user:

Alexs-iPhone:~ tayloryoung$

whereas it used to be

Taylors-MacbookAir:~ tayloryoung$

When I run
 Alexs-iPhone:~ tayloryoung$ last

I only see tayloryoung as a user, so it doesn't look like there is any activity by anyone else. But I'm not sure what caused the change and if there is any cause for concern.

Any suggestions on how to check for foreign activity or how to reverse the changes would be appreciated.

Comment: Note to close-voters - it's not 'too broad' at all, it's a simple, recurring [percieved] issue with a simple explanation - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal or https://superuser.com/questions/451229/why-is-the-name-of-my-computer-wrong-in-terminal

Comment: This is not an actual problem or indication of anything significant, it's just a bit confusing. Your local DNS server is confused about what device is using which IP address, and your Mac is inheriting its confusion.