# WINS/NetBios on public network

Tags: wireless-networking, macos-mojave, netbios

Every time I visit a certain local coffee shop and connect to their wifi, my command prompt in Terminal changes to `DavidsApleWatch:~ <my_username>$`. Bluetooth is disabled and I've confirmed that there is no Apple Watch connected to my device. In System Preferences > Network > WINS, I see the NetBIOS name has been set to 'DAVIDSAPLEWATCH'.

I admittedly don't know much about networking, but I'm concerned about whether connecting to this network is a security issue or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the name of my computer wrong in terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/451229/why-is-the-name-of-my-computer-wrong-in-terminal)