# Get the sharing dynamic computer name from CLI on MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line

Is there a way to get the string in the screenshot from a CLI utility on macOS 12.6 or later? (some things were censored for obvious reasons).

[image]

I tried these:

```
scutil --get HostName
scutil --get LocalHostName
scutil --get ComputerName
```

but none of them returned what I was looking for.
My Google searches haven't helped since I don't quite know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some **dig**ging, I found both why and how to get the exact string printed there.

As per [this](https://superuser.com/a/451243/1747793) previous answer to a question relating to MacOS hostnames, the one-liner solution to get this from CLI would be to run:

`dig +short -x $(ipconfig getifaddr en0) | sed 's/\.$//'`

The way this string is composed is using:

- the NetBIOS name which could be obtained with: `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server NetBIOSName`
- a reversed `ciaddr ip` which one can get with: `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep ciaddr | awk -F ' = ' '{print $2}'` . By reversed I mean the decimal representation of each octet is reversed, not the whole string. So `101.102.203.204` becomes `204.203.102.101`
- some sort of network group, couldn't find a CLI way to obtain it locally, without querying the DNS server.
- the domain_name string, which one can get with: `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep "domain_name (string)" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'`

But the one liner should suffice.